# Issue with Nested If/While/If statement

Tags: python, if-statement, while-loop

As a D&D aficionado, I have written out a script to perform any attack and damage rolls for any specified die, including what happens in the event of a critical attack roll (20).

```
from random import randint

atk_roll = 20
hit_mod = 6
atk_hit = atk_roll + hit_mod
die = 'd10'
dmg_mod = 4
rolls = 1

def dice_roller(x, y, z):
    y1 = int(y.strip('d'))
    dict = {}
    results = []
    step = 1
    while step <= z:
        die = randint(1,y1)
        results.append(die)
        step += 1
    if atk_roll == 20:
        total = (sum(results)+dmg_mod) + (y1*z)
        pct_dmg = total / (((y1*z)+dmg_mod) + (y1*z))
    else:
        total = sum(results) + dmg_mod
        pct_dmg = total / ((y1*z)+dmg_mod)
    dict.update({'Attack Roll: ' + f'{atk_roll} + {hit_mod} = {x}':
                {'Damage Roll: ' + f'{z}' + y:
                {'Rolls': results, 'Total Damage': total, 'Pct_Damage': f'{pct_dmg:.0%}'}}})
    print(dict)

print(dice_roller(atk_hit, die, rolls))

{'Attack Roll: 20 + 6 = 26': {'Damage Roll: 1d10': {'Rolls': [4], 'Total Damage': 18, 'Pct_Damage': '75%'}}}
None
```

The issue becomes when I introduce a new "if/else" statement to account for a missed attack. The only roll that does not work is a critical roll:

```
from random import randint

atk_roll = 20
hit_mod = 6
atk_hit = atk_roll + hit_mod
die = 'd10'
dmg_mod = 4
rolls = 1
ac = 15

def dice_roller(x, y, z):
    y1 = int(y.strip('d'))
    dict = {}
    results = []
    step = 1
    if x >= ac:
        while step <= z:
            die = randint(1,y1)
            results.append(die)
            step += 1
            if atk_roll == 20:
                total = (sum(results)+dmg_mod) + (y1*z)
                pct_dmg = total / (((y1*z)+dmg_mod) + (y1*z))
            else:
                total = sum(results) + dmg_mod
                pct_dmg = total / ((y1*z)+dmg_mod)
                dict.update({'Attack Roll: ' + f'{atk_roll} + {hit_mod} = {x}':
                            {'Damage Roll: ' + f'{z}' + y:
                            {'Rolls': results, 'Total Damage': total, 'Pct_Damage': f'{pct_dmg:.0%}'}}})
            print(dict)
    else:
        print('Your attack missed')

print(dice_roller((atk_hit), die, rolls))
{}
None
```

When I change the value of "atk_roll" in the second script back to "randint(1,20)", the code works exactly as intended, noting when an attack misses or returning the dictionary of values if the attack hits. I cannot for the life of me figure out why the code is returning a blank dict only when "atk_roll" = 20. Does it have something to do with the nesting syntax of if/while/if? Thanks!

Comment: elaborate on what this code does.

Comment: Please try to trace through the logic of your code yourself. See https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ for advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the second code snippet you provided: the if-else block `if ask_roll == 20:`
will always be taken and therefore your dictionary will not be populated with values as the `atk_roll` value is always 20. This is because your `dict` is being populated in the following `else`.

This differs from your first piece of code as `dict` is updated every time the function is called as its located outside of any conditional statements.

I would need more details about what your code does to provide a detailed solution but I will attempt to give a high-level solution. If you are trying to update the dictionary regardless if your `atk_roll` is equal to 20 then the update should be outside the nested `else` block in your conditional statement checking if `atk_roll` is equal to 20. This code snippet is included below.

```
if atk_roll == 20:
    total = (sum(results)+dmg_mod) + (y1*z)
    pct_dmg = total / (((y1*z)+dmg_mod) + (y1*z))
else:
    total = sum(results) + dmg_mod
    pct_dmg = total / ((y1*z)+dmg_mod)
dict.update({'Attack Roll: ' + f'{atk_roll} + {hit_mod} = {x}':
                            {'Damage Roll: ' + f'{z}' + y:
                            {'Rolls': results, 'Total Damage': total, 'Pct_Damage': f'{pct_dmg:.0%}'}}})
```

Comment: Taking the dictionary out of the if/else loop worked, thank you! I swear I took everything else out of the loops except that -_-

Comment: No problem! As some future advice when having logic issues, tracing through he code yourself and possibly writing down on paper the trace of the code depending on conditional statements, loops, etc can help debug many of these issues.